# HTML5 directive breaks Flexible Layout

Tags: html, css

I have big fun playing with Flexible Layout (`display: flex`) and I am impressed with its capabilities. However, I encountered a problem and it is somehow related to `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I would like to create simple page. Header and footer (both 50px height), and content which should take remaining space. Header and footer should always be visible, so no scroll should appear even if content is longer that screen.

Please, take a look into following snippet

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .header {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .content {
            flex-grow: 1;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .footer {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
<head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

It works fine. Header is on the top, footer on the bottom and content takes remaining space. However, if I add directive `<!DOCTYPE html>` then content is 0px height and header is next to footer. Content is not expanded.

This is how it should look:
[image]

And this is how it looks with `<!DOCTYPE html>`
[image]

Anyone know what is the cause? How to fix it? Why this directive has such big influence on rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use HTML5 standard mode when `<!DOCTYPE html>` persists, flex layout cannot be used as you wish. To produce expected result you need to change CSS styles styles for container class by following example

`.container{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}`

Using this css-trick you will be consists both with html5 and html4.

Comment: You can also use `position: absolute` with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` on `body` element.

Answer (score 3):

Without !DOCTYPE your browser goes to [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and causes the different [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

Mateusz's code seems to work fine.

Comment: I probably know what you mean: `In Quirks mode the height of the body element is 100%, as opposite to being determined by its content. (If you want 100% height for body in standards mode, set html, body { height: 100% } in CSS.)`